# What is the difference between maxPoolSize and throttleLimit in the Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring-batch, threadpool

I would like to know the difference between maxPoolSize and throttleLimit while using in the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for batch operation? Are there any criteria while choosing the corresponding values?

When I configured throttleLimit > maxPoolSize, Spring Batch job did not end. What is the reason behind it?

**Configuration(Job not ending even after receiving null in IteamReader)**

```
batch:
    chunkSize: 1
    maxPoolSize: 20
    throttleLimit: 40
    queueSize: 5
    coreSize: 5
```

**Configuration(Working):**

```
batch:
    chunkSize: 1
    maxPoolSize: 20
    throttleLimit: 10
    queueSize: 5
    coreSize: 5
```